# Change Java memory for MATLAB through text?

Tags: java, matlab, memory

It seems I've screwed up. I changed the java memory in MATLAB properties to 4GB (I have 16GB on the comp) and now MATLAB does not run. Is there a way to revert this in a .ini file or something? I do not have administrative rights so a method which does not require one would be great. However if the only way is with administrative rights then I can probably work something out.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The modifications are stored in `matlabprefs.mat` in the `prefdir` in the user path (unless you modified `java.opts`, which would require admin rights, however).

To find the location of your `prefdir`, start Matlab without java.

1. Open a terminal/command window
2. Navigate to your Matlab installation (if it is not already on the path)
3. In the `bin` directory, start `matlab -nojvm`
4. Run the command `prefdir`
5. Close Matlab, navigate to the prefdir folder and clean out the preferences to reset Matlab, and start over. If there is something important in the preferences, add back the files one by one until you break Matlab again.

Comment: thankyouuuu you're a life saver lol... I'll try not to break it again >_>;